# finding median of multiple samples

Tags: quantiles, median

I have the following problem:

(1) I get a package with many samples with values
(2) I have reasonable time to calculate whatever i want and keep in memory any info i want, but not all of the samples (the samples are very large, I can keep a few MB of data)
(3) I drop the package and go to step (1) with a new package, unless no more packages
(4) Use all kept information to calculate the 10% percentile \ median \ 90% percentile

Can it be done?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

You don't describe the process by which you are receiving the data
well enough for a solid answer. What follows is speculation that might
be helpful.

If it is feasible to take a *random* sample of 100 values from among
a huge number of values (say 100,000) you might get sufficiently close.

Suppose you have 100,000 values that happen to be distributed
$\mathsf{Norm}(100, 15).$ Then the 10th, 50th and 90th percentiles
of the population are about 81, 100, 119, from R as follows:

```
qnorm(c(.1,.5,.9), 100, 15)
[1]  80.77673 100.00000 119.22327
```

If you were able to take 100 observations at random from among
100,000, you might get approximate respective percentiles
83, 100, 119, as below:

```
set.seed(2020)
x = rnorm(10^5, 100, 15)
s = sample(x, 100)
quantile(s, c(.1,.5,.9))
      10%       50%       90% 
 82.71281  99.60697 118.63415
```

Not perfect but perhaps good enough for practical purposes.

In you have any idea that batches may be random samples from the
entire population of values, it might suffice to find these quantiles from
the first 'package'. Then do the same for a few additional 'packages'
to see if results are similar from one 'package' to the next.

For example, if the values are exponentially distributed with mean 100, and you you look at 1000 values from each of several packages
you might get results similar to those below. I chose to look at
exponential data for this example, because sample quantiles (especially the 90th) are more
variable than for normal data.

```
set.seed(1122)
quantile(rexp(1000, 1/100), c(.1,.5,.9))
      10%       50%       90% 
 12.46320  67.56755 235.70446 

quantile(rexp(1000, 1/100), c(.1,.5,.9))
      10%       50%       90% 
 11.00286  78.51803 236.77132 

quantile(rexp(1000, 1/100), c(.1,.5,.9))
      10%       50%       90% 
 11.05049  74.76116 240.70067 

quantile(rexp(1000, 1/100), c(.1,.5,.9))
       10%        50%        90% 
  9.464616  67.543288 248.137799
```

The respective population quantiles are about 11, 69, and 230.